# How is AdS/Schwarzschild asymptotically AdS?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

A simple GR question. Consider planar Schwarzschild-AdS solution $$ds^2=\frac{R^2}{z^2}\left(-fdt^2+dx^2+\frac{dz^2}{f}\right)$$ where $f=1-(z/z_0)^d$ for constant $z_0$. I've heard this referred to as "asymptotically adS" (locally at least). In what limit does this tend to adS? Towards the conformal boundary ($z\to 0$), I simply find Minkowski space, right? (to be slightly more precise I should perhaps say the defining function $\mathcal{Z}^2\equiv z^2/R^2$ vanishes linearly on the boundary, and the metric from which we can induce a metric on the boundary is just Minkowski, $(-dt^2+dx^2+dz^2)$.) At the black hole horizon ($z=z_0$), I just find an Euclidean space with metric $\propto dx^2$. At the null boundary $z\to\infty$, I'm not sure what happens. Anyway, I don't see adS emerge anywhere? What am I missing? Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To leading order in $z$ for small $z$, $f=1+O(z^d)$. Therefore the metric becomes
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = \frac{R^2}{z^2}\left(-dt^2 + dx^2 + dz^2\right)
\end{equation}
which describes a [patch of AdS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-de_Sitter_space#Coordinate_patches). The metric is related to Minkowski space by a conformal transformation.

Comment: Ok thanks. Am I right in saying that the conformal boundary metric (z=0) is Minkowski but for small but non-zero z it asymptotes to AdS then?

Comment: @user984949 Asymptotically as $z\rightarrow 0$ the metric is equivalent to Minkowski up to a conformal transformation. I don't know the term "conformal boundary metric" but I would guess that's the definition.

Comment: great, thanks !